# PostgreSQL IDLE process

Tags: postgresql, api, rest, go

I have a REST API wirtten on golang, it works with PostgreSQL 10. I can see if I will refresh my web page a lot of times Postgree will use all of the RAM on the server and after that server will be rebooted.

As I found out, postgresql dosn't close connections. It always on "idle" state.

this is go code example

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name, category, subcategory from usertable")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error", err)
}

for rows.Next() {
    bk := User{}
    err = rows.Scan(&bk.Name, bk.Category, &bk.Subcategory)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }
    arrayUsers = append(arrayUsers, bk)
}

defer rows.Close()
```

as you can see I close my connection but if i run 'htop' on postgresql server i can see that every connection in idle state

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYlHb.png)

Comment: `db` (type `*sql.DB` [which is a connection pool]) keeps idle connections and if properly used will *re-use* them when needed, this usually works without any problems unless your postgres server has a limit on open connections set to a number that is too small to handle the load.

Comment: It is not the database server's job to close connections (unless there is a problem that necessitates it), it is the task of the client, that is, your application. Don't open and close connections all the time, as that is very expensive. Use a connection pool instead. The excessive RAM usage is a different problem that you'll have to investigate. If excessive RAM usage causes a reboot, you have an operating system bug.

Comment: @mkopriva but if I'm sure that i will not re-use them, can i close them? because each of idle connections uses RAM.

Comment: You could close the pool which should release all of its connections, unless you're leaking some. Note also that the code you've provided does not prove that you're closing  the rows at the proper time, i.e. your code is not embedded in a function body so we can only guess when the defered function will be invoked, for all we know this piece of code could be in an infinite loop in which case the defered function ain't gonna be called anytime soon.

Comment: Keep in mind that in general you SHOULD not be closing the pool, it is instead recommended to have one pool instance per app and have that instance be used throughout the app. Closing it may fix your immediate problem but it is very likely that the cause is some other misuse of resources or limitations of your environment.

Comment: so, as i understand i should use db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute)

to close conection in a minute, for example

Comment: An "idle" session isn't really a problem - "idle in transaction" would. If you think you have too many idle sessions, then you need to configure your connection pool, to close them after they have been idle for too long